# In an array containing objects, changing one item's property doesn't change the object itself

Tags: swift

This will not happen if I just change the properties instead of replacing the reference to a new object.

Here is a class *Person*, which is a reference type,

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Here is an instance of *Person*,

```
var someone = Person(firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "Appleseed")
```

then I make an array containing values of type Person

```
var lotsOfPeople = [someone, someone, someone]
```

I suppose *lotsOfPeople* containing 3 references to *someone*.
But if I change the third value in lotsOfPeople,

```
lotsOfPeople[2] = Person(firstName: "Lucy", lastName: "Swift")
```

*someone* itself isn't changed.

```
print(someone.firstName) // Johnny
```

I think it means *lotsOfPeople[2]* is not a reference to *someone*.
How could this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing the reference at `lotsOfPeople[2]` to point to a new object. That is why the original `Person` is not changed.

If you did `lotsOfPeople[2].firstName = "Lucy"` then it would change.

Or do:

```
let person = lotsOfPeople[2]
person.firstName = "Lucy"
```

then you would also see the original change.